# ¿Por qué del latín "teneo" quedó español "tengo", con una "g" intercalada?

Tags: etimología, verbos, latín

¿Por qué del latín *teneo* quedó el español *tengo*, con una *g* intercalada?

Answer (score 7):

El grupo *-ng-* aparece en la primera persona del indicativo del verbo *tener* y otros similares debido a la analogía, es decir, un proceso en el cual los hablantes calcan unas formas sobre otras. La historia es más o menos así:

### Palatalización de /g/ ante vocales anteriores

En una determinada etapa de la evolución del romance, la /g/ se palatalizó en /j/ (*[yod](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yod_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica))*) ante las vocales anteriores /e/, /i/. Esto implicó que apareciera una nasal seguida de *yod* al final de muchos verbos que en latín terminaban *-ngere*.

Así por ejemplo se palatalizó la /g/ en los verbos *ringere*, *plangere* y 
*tangere*, y al quedar en contacto /n/ + /j/ el resultado fue la nasal palatal /ɲ/, representada por *ñ* (en español resultaron *reñir*, *plañir* y *tañer* respectivamente).

El asunto es que en la primera persona del singular del presente del indicativo la vocal de la conjugación era *-ō*, luego acortada *-o*, que es posterior, por lo cual no provocaba la palatalización de la /g/. Es decir que los verbos tenían una raíz terminada en nasal palatal en todas las personas menos en la primera del singular, donde se preservaba la /g/. Esta excepción eventualmente sería anulada por analogía, pero entretanto...

### Palatalización de /n/ ante *yod*

Algo similar a lo anterior pasaba cuando la *yod* provenía de un sonido /e/ o /i/ que se había hecho no silábico, como en la conjugación de primera persona del singular del presente de indicativo de *tenere*, que era *teneō* y que debió pasar a algo así como *tenĭo* /tenjo/, o la de *venire*, que era *veniō*. Como en el caso anterior el grupo /n/ + /j/ dio /ɲ/ (nuestra *ñ*). Así es como quedó la conjugación en portugués, de hecho (con /ɲ/ representada por *nh*: *eu tenho* "yo tengo", *eu venho* "yo vengo").

### Reinterpretación de las dos formas en una

Una vez obtenida la nasal palatal en el final de las raíces de estos dos tipos de verbos, no había manera de que los hablantes supiesen cuál de los dos mecanismos era el que había llevado a la aparición de /ɲ/. Los verbos latinos terminados en *-ngere* se conjugaban en todas las personas, menos la primera del singular, con la palatal /ɲ/, mientras que en la primera del singular alternaban /ng/ (que era el desarrollo fonético normal) y /ɲ/ (que se iba extendiendo por analogía). Vale decir que el verbo que hoy escribimos *ceñir* se conjugaba *cingo* o *ciño*; *tañer* daba *tango* o *taño*, etc. En los verbos donde /ɲ/ provenía de /n/ + /j/ no había esa alternancia.

Eventualmente, por razones que sólo podemos especular, los hablantes comenzaron a extender por analogía la *-g-* intermedia preservada en los verbos descendientes de los latinos en *-ngere* en la primera persona del singular a los otros verbos que, como éstos, tenían una raíz terminada en nasal palatal al conjugarse en otras personas. El razonamiento inconsciente pudo haber sido que **los verbos con raíces terminadas en nasal palatal debían tener una primera persona del singular con *-g-*.**

Esta alternancia terminó afianzándose sólo en unos pocos verbos muy usados, como *tener* y *venir*; se extendió enseguida a otro con una estructura fonética similar, *poner*, y por un proceso similar, a *salir* y *valer* (cuyas formas de primera del singular deberían regularmente ser *sallo* y *vallo*). Hay testimonio escrito incluso de las formas *duelgo* (de *doler*) y *suelgo* (de *soler*). En todos los casos parece que se razonó que había que infijar una *-g-* en la primera persona.

La mayor parte de los verbos donde existía la alternancia citada, sin embargo, terminó perdiéndola, de ahí que *ceñir*, *tañer*, *plañir* y demás sean hoy regulares en ese sentido.

Fuente: *Del latín al español. I. Fonología y morfología históricas de la lengua española*, de Paul M. Lloyd.

Answer (score 2):

Muchos verbos irregulares se formaron a partir de principios generales fonológicos o leyes fonéticas del sistema español que han llevado a cambios fonéticos a partir del latín vulgar.

Estas leyes sufren con frecuencia alteraciones debidas principalmente a la influencia de otros sonidos de la misma palabra. La más importante es la de yod. **Se llama yod a todo sonido de i semivocal o semiconsonante; a toda e en hiato, y a la i desarrollada por las consonantes palatales**.

La influencia de yod se deja sentir, no sólo en la a, sino también en las demás vocales. Su articulación cerrada se propaga a las vocales que la preceden, y de este modo, las que debieran ser abiertas en el latín vulgar, quedan cerradas y evolucionan como tales.

Por esto la e y la o, que diptongan en ie, ue [serra > sierra; morte > muerte], no pueden diptongar cuando van seguidas de yod: [latín] pectu > [español] pecho; **[latín] teneo > [español] tengo**; [latín] nocte > [español] noche; [latín] folia > [español] hoja. Ésta es la excepción castellana más importante a la ley de diptongación de ambas vocales.

Referencias:

1. [Cómo explicar los verbos irregulares](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Verbos%20irregulares-C%C3%B3mo%20explicarlos.htm)
2. [JOD/Yod (hispanoteca)](http://hispanoteca.eu/Lexikon%20der%20Linguistik/j/JOD%20%20%20Yod.htm)
3. [Apuntes de lengua: Resumen de Fonética histórica](http://elarlequindehielo.obolog.es/apuntes-lengua-resumen-fonetica-historica-195706)

Comment: @blonfu. Gracias. Medianamente corregido. El enlace original tenía espacios en la url, así que he tenido que compartir el enlace a una sección anterior. En cualquier caso el contenido es muy parecido al del primer enlace, pues se trata del mismo autor.

Comment: @blonfu I fixed the link.