# ¿De dónde vienen las formas irregulares del verbo haber?

Tags: gramática, verbos, historia, voseo, formas-irregulares

Me interesaría saber cómo se han desarrollado las formas irregulares del presente de indicativo del verbo *haber*. Es obvio que no se dice *"tú habes", "ella habe" y "nosotros habemos*". Supongo que en su desarrollo del latín se fue en algún momento aquella sílaba.

Llevo bastante tiempo buscando porque pensé que era fácil de encontrar, googleándolo tanto en inglés como en español, pero el internet no me quiere decir el porqué. :D

También quisiera saber por qué solamente la forma del vosotros se quedó con el *hab-*. Me llamó la atención, porque en el voseo rioplatense se fue de nuevo. No se dice *"vos habés"*, y en el voseo chileno la forma *tú hai* es la que se usa preferibilmente, en vez de *"tú habí(s)"* que me parece más lógica.

¿Alguien tiene ideas?

Comment: Mi fuente de consulta está en casa pero si mal no recuerdo las formas cortas de *haber* son simplemente producto de su uso frecuente. Lo más usado se abrevia. Dos sílabas para las formas simples más usadas de un verbo auxiliar eran mucho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En el paso del latín al español hubo debilitamiento importante de las consonantes oclusivas sonoras, con varios episodios. En primer lugar, las oclusivas sonoras /b d ɡ/ pasaron a ser fricativas, [β ð ɣ], entre vocales y en ciertos otros contextos (esto sigue siendo válido hoy). En segundo lugar, ya debilitadas de esta manera, muchas de estas fricativas sordas fueron elididas completamente entre vocales. La dental [ð] cae casi en todos los casos, la velar [ɣ] en unos cuantos, y la labial [β] en unos pocos, unos de los cuales es precisamente la conjugación del verbo *habēre*.

Además de este proceso ocurría que la vocal /e/ no acentuada, en ciertos contextos, se transformaba en semivocal, pasaba a ser /i̯/ (una *i* corta) y después /j/ (*yod*, una [aproximante palatal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aproximante_palatal)). Esta *yod* aparecía en las conjugaciones de muchos verbos y a veces reemplazaba a la consonante anterior, cuando ésta era una de las perdidas por el proceso explicado antes. Esto evitaba, además, que se produjera un hiato entre dos vocales. Por ejemplo, la primera persona del singular del verbo *vedēre* "ver", era *videō*, que evolucionó a algo así como [beði̯o] > [bei̯o] > [bejo], escrito *veyo*.

Al final la *yod* comenzó a extenderse a otras formas de los verbos, donde no era resultado del proceso de semivocalización de una /i/ o una /e/ sino simplemente un artificio para romper el hiato entre vocales, y así hay registrados infinitivos como *cayer, creyer, oyir, rayer, reyir, veyer*. Estos fueron luego devueltos a sus formas regulares, aunque algunas de sus conjugaciones sufrieron otros cambios (como la [inserción de una /g/ epentética en la primera persona](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21943/por-qu%C3%A9-del-lat%C3%ADn-teneo-qued%C3%B3-espa%C3%B1ol-tengo-con-una-g-intercalada/21949#21949) a la que se refería otra pregunta).

Como ya se dijo, la /b/ intervocálica en general no se perdió como la /d/, pero hubo excepciones, y una de ellas fue el verbo "haber" (escrito muchas veces *haver* o *aver*), posiblemente porque era de uso muy frecuente. Las palabras muy usadas tienden, en todas las lenguas, a ser acortadas y a preservar irregularidades (las irregularidades pueden contribuir, incluso, a que esas formas abreviadas sean distinguibles unas de otras). Desde el momento en que "haber" pasó a usarse como auxiliar para los tiempos compuestos se volvió omnipresente y las formas regulares se fueron erosionando.

La primera persona singular del presente de *habēre* era *habeō*, que dio [aβi̯o] y luego, con la caída de la fricativa labial, [ai̯o]. Las otras formas del singular, *habēs* y *habet*, dieron [aes] y [at] luego de elidir la fricativa. Sólo las formas de 1era. y 2da. pl., *habēmus* y *habētis*, conservaron alternativas largas, dando [aβemos]/[emos] y [aβei̯s]/[ei̯s]; la 3era. pl. *habent* se simplificó drásticamente [aβent] > [ant]. Estas formas se simplificaron todavía más de las maneras habituales: [aes] se acortó a [as] y [at] y [ant] perdieron la oclusiva final.

Lo único realmente radical que ocurrió después fue que la 1era. sing. perdió de sopetón la /o/ final; así [ai̯o] pasó a [ai̯], que por simplificación regular de los diptongos pasó a [e] (hoy escrito *he*).

Al final quedamos con la conjugación actual, con la única rareza de que para la 1era. pl. conservamos las alternativas *habemos* y *hemos*, y en la 2da. pl. quedó la forma larga *habéis*.

La forma impersonal *hay* tiene también una historia curiosa. Una forma de decir en latín que "había algo en un lugar" era emplear la locución *habet ibi*, que significaba literalmente "tiene allí". Ese *ibi* es el origen del sonido [i̯] que hoy escribimos como *y* en *hay*. Es también el origen de la partícula *y* en francés, que aparece en *il y a* (compárese *Il a une voiture* "Él tiene un automóvil" vs. *Il y a une voiture là* "Hay un automóvil allá"). Algo similar ocurre en inglés, donde el "haber algo en un lugar" se expresa usando el demostrativo *there* más el verbo *to be*, que funciona como auxiliar.

Fuente: *Del latín al español. I. Fonología y morfología históricas de la lengua española*, de Paul M. Lloyd.

Comment: Super interesante, gracias por compartir!