# How many -iar verbs are there?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, conjugación

Tonight in my Spanish class we were discussing preterit conjugations of verbs.  One of the verbs we were looking at was **limpiar**, which in the 3rd person has the conjugation of **limpió**.  I pointed out that if you didn't know that this was an **-ar** verb, then you could easily confuse the conjugated form for an **-er/-ir** verb.  My teacher suggested that there are not that many such verbs, and we identified 4 of them: Limpiar, Estudiar, Refriarse and Divorciarse

My question is simply how many **-iar** verbs are there in Spanish that conjugate to **-ió** in the past tense?  My gut feeling is that there are more than I would expect.

Comment: Related: [_How common are each of the three categories of verbs?_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31455/12637)

Comment: Regular verbs ending in *-ar* all conjugate in this way regardless of what's there before the *-a*. Just as you say *am-ó, cant-ó, mir-ó*, you say *limpi-ó*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *Enclave RAE*, searching for words ending in *-iar* and filtering by the 'verb' category, there are 950 entries, from *[abrenunciar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0AWaMwq)* to *[zurriar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cYhr0jT)*. The thing is, this list includes duplicates if the verbs have more than one meaning. If I process the list and remove the duplicates, the final list of Spanish verbs ending in *-iar* contains **459 verbs** (note that the list includes obsolete verbs and some pronominal verbs such as *calosfriarse*):

> abrenunciar,
>   abreviar,
>   acalumniar,
>   acariciar,
>   acequiar,
>   acodiciar,
>   acopiar,
>   acuantiar,
>   acuciar,
>   acudiciar,
>   adiar,
>   afiar,
>   afiliar,
>   afiuciar,
>   afuciar,
>   agenciar,
>   agobiar,
>   agraciar,
>   agraviar,
>   agremiar,
>   agriar,
>   aguciar,
>   ahuciar,
>   aindiar,
>   ajuiciar,
>   ajusticiar,
>   alaciarse,
>   albedriar,
>   albriciar,
>   aleviar,
>   algaliar,
>   aliar,
>   alimpiar,
>   aliviar,
>   almadiar,
>   aluciar,
>   amelarchiarse,
>   amnistiar,
>   ampliar,
>   amustiar,
>   aneciarse,
>   anestesiar,
>   angustiar,
>   anidiar,
>   anoticiar,
>   ansiar,
>   antuviar,
>   anunciar,
>   aparroquiar,
>   apreciar,
>   apremiar,
>   aprestigiar,
>   apropiar,
>   aquerenciarse,
>   arpegiar,
>   arranciarse,
>   arreciar,
>   arriar,
>   artificiar,
>   asalariar,
>   asediar,
>   aseriarse,
>   asfixiar,
>   asociar,
>   asubiar,
>   ataviar,
>   atediar,
>   atericiarse,
>   atibiar,
>   atiriciarse,
>   atrofiar,
>   aturriar,
>   auspiciar,
>   autofinanciar,
>   autografiar,
>   auxiliar,
>   avaliar,
>   avariciar,
>   averiar,
>   aviar,
>   aviciar,
>   beneficiar,
>   biografiar,
>   bolliciar,
>   braquiar,
>   cablegrafiar,
>   calabriar,
>   calcografiar,
>   caligrafiar,
>   calofriarse,
>   caloniar,
>   calosfriarse,
>   calumniar,
>   cambiar,
>   camiar,
>   canmiar,
>   canturriar,
>   cariar,
>   cartografiar,
>   chapiar,
>   cherriar,
>   chiar,
>   chipiar,
>   chirriar,
>   chiviar,
>   ciar,
>   cinematografiar,
>   circunstanciar,
>   codiciar,
>   cofinanciar,
>   colegiar,
>   columpiar,
>   comediar,
>   comerciar,
>   comisariar,
>   compendiar,
>   concienciar,
>   conciliar,
>   conferenciar,
>   confiar,
>   congeniar,
>   congloriar,
>   congraciar,
>   consorciar,
>   consustanciarse,
>   contagiar,
>   contrariar,
>   contumeriar,
>   copiar,
>   coreografiar,
>   correntiar,
>   criar,
>   cromolitografiar,
>   cuantiar,
>   cuchichiar,
>   curiar,
>   custodiar,
>   dactilografiar,
>   defiar,
>   defoliar,
>   deliciarse,
>   demasiarse,
>   demediar,
>   denunciar,
>   depreciar,
>   derrubiar,
>   desafiar,
>   desafiuciar,
>   desafuciar,
>   desagraciar,
>   desagraviar,
>   desahuciar,
>   desaparroquiar,
>   desapreciar,
>   desapropiarse,
>   desasociar,
>   desataviar,
>   desaviar,
>   descambiar,
>   descarriar,
>   desconfiar,
>   descontagiar,
>   descriarse,
>   desendemoniar,
>   desenhastiar,
>   desgraciar,
>   desliar,
>   desmemoriarse,
>   desperdiciar,
>   despreciar,
>   desprestigiar,
>   despropiar,
>   desquiciar,
>   destapiar,
>   desustanciar,
>   desvariar,
>   desviar,
>   diferenciar,
>   difiuciar,
>   digladiar,
>   diligenciar,
>   diluviar,
>   dimidiar,
>   disociar,
>   distanciar,
>   divorciar,
>   domiciliar,
>   efigiar,
>   ejecutoriar,
>   elogiar,
>   embarriar,
>   emburriar,
>   embutiar,
>   empaliar,
>   empapuciar,
>   encabriar,
>   encalabriar,
>   encomiar,
>   endemoniar,
>   enfastiar,
>   enfiar,
>   enfriar,
>   enfuriarse,
>   engaliar,
>   engarfiar,
>   engaviar,
>   engraciar,
>   enhastiar,
>   enjarciar,
>   enjuiciar,
>   enlabiar,
>   enlaciar,
>   enlejiar,
>   enmustiar,
>   enneciarse,
>   ennoviarse,
>   enquiciar,
>   enrabiar,
>   enranciar,
>   enreciar,
>   enriar,
>   enripiar,
>   enrubiar,
>   enseriar,
>   ensuciar,
>   entenciar,
>   enterciar,
>   entibiar,
>   entirriarse,
>   entrecriarse,
>   entremediar,
>   enturbiar,
>   enunciar,
>   enviar,
>   enviciar,
>   envidiar,
>   epigrafiar,
>   escagarruciarse,
>   escaliar,
>   escalofriar,
>   escanciar,
>   escariar,
>   escarpiar,
>   escofiar,
>   escoliar,
>   esenciarse,
>   esfriar,
>   esgrafiar,
>   espaciar,
>   especiar,
>   esperriar,
>   espiar,
>   espurriar,
>   esquiar,
>   esquiciar,
>   estenografiar,
>   estipendiar,
>   estriar,
>   estudiar,
>   evidenciar,
>   excoriar,
>   exfoliar,
>   exiliar,
>   exordiar,
>   expatriar,
>   expiar,
>   expoliar,
>   expropiar,
>   extasiar,
>   extraviar,
>   fasquiar,
>   fastidiar,
>   feriar,
>   fiar,
>   filiar,
>   financiar,
>   foliar,
>   fotocopiar,
>   fotografiar,
>   fotolitografiar,
>   franquiciar,
>   gazmiar,
>   gerenciar,
>   gloriar,
>   guiar,
>   hastiar,
>   hemenciar,
>   herniarse,
>   hiperestesiar,
>   hipertrofiarse,
>   hipostasiar,
>   historiar,
>   homiciarse,
>   imbiar,
>   impropiar,
>   incendiar,
>   incordiar,
>   indiciar,
>   industriar,
>   inebriar,
>   influenciar,
>   ingeniar,
>   iniciar,
>   injuriar,
>   insidiar,
>   inteligenciar,
>   intercambiar,
>   interfoliar,
>   intermediar,
>   inventariar,
>   inviar,
>   invidiar,
>   irradiar,
>   irreverenciar,
>   jadiar,
>   jarciar,
>   jipiar,
>   justiciar,
>   justipreciar,
>   liar,
>   licenciar,
>   lidiar,
>   limpiar,
>   lipidiar,
>   lisiar,
>   litofotografiar,
>   litografiar,
>   lixiviar,
>   ludiar,
>   lujuriar,
>   magiar,
>   malcriar,
>   maleficiar,
>   maliciar,
>   martiriar,
>   matrimoniar,
>   mecanografiar,
>   mediar,
>   menospreciar,
>   miar,
>   mimeografiar,
>   miniar,
>   multicopiar,
>   murciar,
>   murriar,
>   mustiar,
>   negociar,
>   nerviar,
>   notariar,
>   noticiar,
>   noviar,
>   obsequiar,
>   obviar,
>   ociar,
>   odiar,
>   oficiar,
>   oprobiar,
>   paliar,
>   parodiar,
>   pendenciar,
>   penitenciar,
>   pesiar,
>   piar,
>   pifiar,
>   pipiar,
>   pirriar,
>   plagiar,
>   policopiar,
>   porfiar,
>   potenciar,
>   preciar,
>   prejuiciar,
>   preludiar,
>   premiar,
>   prenunciar,
>   presagiar,
>   presenciar,
>   presidiar,
>   prestigiar,
>   principiar,
>   privilegiar,
>   promediar,
>   prontuariar,
>   pronunciar,
>   propiciar,
>   providenciar,
>   quintaesenciar,
>   rabiar,
>   radiar,
>   radiografiar,
>   radiotelegrafiar,
>   ranciar,
>   rebudiar,
>   recambiar,
>   reconciliar,
>   recriar,
>   reenviar,
>   refriar,
>   refugiar,
>   regraciar,
>   reiniciar,
>   relimpiar,
>   remediar,
>   remudiar,
>   renunciar,
>   repatriar,
>   represaliar,
>   repropiarse,
>   repudiar,
>   resabiar,
>   resfriar,
>   residenciar,
>   reverenciar,
>   ripiar,
>   rociar,
>   rujiar,
>   rumiar,
>   saciar,
>   salariar,
>   salmodiar,
>   secuenciar,
>   sentenciar,
>   seriar,
>   serigrafiar,
>   serviciar,
>   silenciar,
>   sitiar,
>   soberbiar,
>   soliloquiar,
>   soliviar,
>   sorripiar,
>   subsidiar,
>   sumariar,
>   sustanciar,
>   tapiar,
>   taquigrafiar,
>   tediarse,
>   telegrafiar,
>   terciar,
>   tertuliar,
>   testimoniar,
>   tibiar,
>   transustanciar,
>   triar,
>   tripudiar,
>   uviar,
>   vaciar,
>   vanagloriarse,
>   variar,
>   vendimiar,
>   veneficiar,
>   venenciar,
>   viciar,
>   vidriar,
>   vigiar,
>   vilipendiar,
>   xerocopiar,
>   xerografiar,
>   zahoriar,
>   zurriar

Comment: I am going to have so much fun when i take this list to my next class!  However there are at least two in this list that I am not sure match my criteria.  EG  "fiar " conjugates as "fio" and not "fió".  I'm not sure if it doesn't count because of the lack or accent, or that it does count because short length -ir/-er verbs also reduce to an accent-less "o".

Comment: @PeterM bear in mind that it is written "fio" but is pronounced "fió". The accent mark is not needed because the word only has one syllable.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that, but I am not at level of nuances of pronunciation yet (but it does raise a good question to ask of my teacher)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
abrenunciar
abreviar
acalumniar
acariciar
acequiar
acodiciar
acopiar
acuantiar
acuciar
acudiciar
adiar
afiar
afiliar
afiuciar
afuciar
agenciar
agobiar
agraciar
agraviar
agremiar
agriar
aguciar
ahuciar
aindiar
ajuiciar
ajusticiar
alaciarse
albedriar
albriciar
aleviar
algaliar
aliar
alimpiar
aliviar
almadiar
aluciar
amelarchiarse
amnistiar
ampliar
amustiar
aneciarse
anestesiar
angustiar
anidiar
anoticiar
ansiar
antuviar
anunciar
aparroquiar
apreciar
apremiar
aprestigiar
apropiar
aquerenciarse
arpegiar
arranciarse
arreciar
arriar
artificiar
asalariar
asediar
aseriarse
asfixiar
asociar
asubiar
ataviar
atediar
atericiarse
atibiar
atiriciarse
atrofiar
aturriar
auspiciar
autofinanciar
autografiar
auxiliar
avaliar
avariciar
averiar
aviar
aviciar
beneficiar
biografiar
bolliciar
braquiar
cablegrafiar
calabriar
calcografiar
caligrafiar
calofriarse
caloniar
calosfriarse
calumniar
cambiar
camiar
canmiar
canturriar
cariar
cartografiar
chapiar
cherriar
chiar
chipiar
chirriar
chiviar
ciar
cinematografiar
circunstanciar
codiciar
cofinanciar
colegiar
columpiar
comediar
comerciar
comisariar
compendiar
concienciar
conciliar
conferenciar
confiar
congeniar
congloriar
congraciar
consorciar
consubstanciarse
consustanciarse
contagiar
contrariar
contumeriar
copiar
coreografiar
correntiar
criar
cromolitografiar
cuantiar
cuchichiar
curiar
custodiar
dactilografiar
defiar
defoliar
deliciarse
demasiarse
demediar
denunciar
depreciar
derrubiar
desafiar
desafiuciar
desafuciar
desagraciar
desagraviar
desahuciar
desaparroquiar
desapreciar
desapropiarse
desasociar
desataviar
desaviar
descambiar
descarriar
desconfiar
descontagiar
descriarse
desendemoniar
desenhastiar
desgraciar
desliar
desmemoriarse
desperdiciar
despreciar
desprestigiar
despropiar
desquiciar
destapiar
desubstanciar
desustanciar
desvariar
desviar
diferenciar
difiuciar
digladiar
diligenciar
diluviar
dimidiar
disociar
distanciar
divorciar
domiciliar
efigiar
ejecutoriar
elogiar
embarriar
emburriar,
```

etc.?

Hint : go to https://dle.rae.es/ and search for words ending in "-iar".

Comment: I'm aware that the RAE dictionary exists but I have never consulted it, and did not know that you could search based on ending